# Apple mail sending duplicate messages

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I own an Early 2011 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.1. I have configured two email accounts with my mail app(one hotmail and another gmail), and both use imap. The problem is that when I send an email to a particular person, the app sends two mails(one duplicate) in place of one. Please help.

EDIT: Upon some troubleshooting I found that this is a problem only with hotmail, my gmail account is working fine.

EDIT: It has fixed by itself. All I can surmise is that there was a problem with the hotmail imap.

Comment: Is it sending it from both accounts ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 nope. two mails from the same account to same recepient.

Comment: Is the message stuck in the Concepts folder first and you manually send it again?

Comment: @Robuust nope. I click the send button only once.

Comment: Only to one user? Does it show sent twice or does the person receive them twice?

Comment: How do you know it sends 2 emails at same time.

Comment: It shows sent twice and the person receives it twice too. I've checked it.